# JQuery adding select field with no duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I avoid any duplicates by adding new select fields in JQuery? I want to add a new select field into existing, but with no repeats. How can I do that? Please, find my code below. Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var max_fields = 20;
  var wrapper = $('.input_fields_wrap');
  var add_list = $('.add_list_field_button');
  var x = 1;

  $(wrapper).on('click', ".remove_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });

  $(document).on('change', '.dimension_NL', function() {
    var i;
    total = 0;
    let vals = [];
    $('.dimension_NL').each(function() {
      vals.push($(this).val());
    });
    for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
      total += parseInt(vals[i]);
    }
    $('#total').text('I don\'t know what to do with all these values : ' + total);
  });

  $(add_list).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append("<div>" +
        "<label>List zwykły</label>" +
        "<label for='dimension_NL'>Gabaryt</label>" +
        "<select name='dimension_NL' class='dimension_NL'>" +
        "<option value='0' selected>Wybierz</option>" +
        "<option value='1'>Gabaryt A</option>" +
        "<option value='2'>Gabaryt B</option>" +
        "</select>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<a href='#' class='remove_field'>Remove</a>"
      );
    }
  });

  $(document).on('change', '.dimension_NL', function() {
    var parent = $(this).val();
    switch (parent) {
      case '1':
        $(this).parent('div').append(
          "<label for='priority_NL'>Priorytet</label>" +
          "<select name='priority_NL'   class='priority_NL'>" +
          "<option value='0' selected>Wybierz</option>" +
          "<option value='1'>Priorytet</option>" +
          "<option value='2'>Ekonomiczny</option>" +
          "</select>"
        );
        break;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='input_fields_wrap'>
  <button class='add_list_field_button'>List zwykły</button>
</div>

<div id='total'></div>
```

Comment: can you explain more? you want to have 2 dropdowns but  he should choose 2 different values ?

Comment: seems like there lot of fixing to be done with your code. 

1. clicking *"Remove"* removes all fields.

2. changing combobox value to `Gabaryt A` adds additional comboboxes (*is this how this should work?*) giving you multiple comboboxes.


3. *coming soon...* :D

Comment: I want only one dropdown when 'Gabaryt A' field from a first select form is active. Unfortunately, I've received much more dropdowns any time when I've changed a select field with dimensions.

Comment: "no repeats". What exactly should not be repeated? Your wording is unclear. Give an example of the expected result.

Comment: Please, run code snippet mode. Every time when you push "List zwykły" button, the Gabaryt select field will appear, with two options - Gabaryt A and Gabaryt B. When you chose "Gabaryt A" option, the new select field will appear. The point is, the new select field is added every time when I changing Gabaryt field and I want to add this field only one, for each "List zwykły". field. 

I have problems with explaining that even in my native language....

Comment: `$(add_list).click` can be changed to `add_list.click` - you already wrapped it in a jQuery object at the top of the code. No point wrapping it again. Anyway, it's adding multiple selects because you're literally inserting the same markup again every time the user selects the A value. Instead, check if it already exists before you do this.

Comment: Alternatively, load all of it together when "add_list" is clicked, but make the second select hidden until "Gabaryt A" is selected. Only then make it visible. That way, you don't get repeats because all that selecting "Gabaryt A" does is make the second select visible. If it's already visible, then nothing changes. If a different option is selected, you could consider hiding it again, if that would make sense for your application.